# Read first column as header in matrix for unsquare matrix

Tags: r, networking, matrix, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to read in an adjacency matrix to create a network in graph
I can read the data in with this:

```
Matrix_One <- read.csv("Network Matrix.csv", header=TRUE)
Matrix <- as.matrix(Matrix_One)
first_network <- graph.adjacency(Matrix, mode= "directed", weighted=NULL)
```

But this doesn't acknowledge the first column are headers as I'm getting this warning message:

> Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted,  : 
>     At structure_generators.c:273 : Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix

Any idea how to get R to read column1 as headers?

Comment: Please show us the first three rows of your csv file and also `head(Matrix)`  and `dim(Matrix)`

Comment: Oops sorry, it is reading the first row as headers but not the first column.

Comment: "Non-square matrix" refers to your matrix having a height different to its width. Compare `nrow(Matrix)` width `ncol(Matrix)` and see how the first column (presumably containing a vertical header) is making your matrix wider than it's tall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd like to drop the first column of your Matrix like this:

`Matrix <- as.matrix(Matrix_One)[,-1]`

If the values of your adjacency matrix are numeric, it might be recommendable to use `data.matrix()` instead of `as.matrix()` to get numeric values instead of strings in your matrix. Often the values in the adjacency matrix are weights corresponding to each edge-weight given as a numeric value.

To get R to read your data as a usable adjacency matrix, consider this:

```
 # Assuming your csv file is like this...
csv <- "X,A,B,C,B,E
        A,0,0,1,0,1
        B,1,0,0,0,0
        C,1,1,0,0,0
        D,1,0,0,0,0
        E,0,0,0,0,0"
# ... with first row and column indicating node name in your network.

# To keep names, we could keep the header and use it as a list of nodes:
Matrix_One <- read.csv2("Network Matrix.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
Nodelist <- names(Matrix_One)[-1]

# The matrix should include the first row (which is data),
# but not the first column (which too contains node-names) of the df:
Matrix <- data.matrix(Matrix_One)[,-1]
# As the matrix is now of the size N by N, row- and colnames makes for a neat matrix:
rownames(Matrix) <- colnames(Matrix) <- Nodelist

# Look at it
Matrix

# Use igraph to make a graph-object and visualize it
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(Matrix, mode="directed", weighted=NULL)
plot(g)
```

The package `graph` is outdated (and removed from CRAN I believe). The above example uses `igrpah` instead, which is a comprehensive network data management package with some nice visualization. The result from the code above will be something like this:

[image]

If you choose to stick to `graph`, your like `first_network <- graph.adjacency(Matrix, mode= "directed", weighted=NULL)` takes the square `Matrix` too.